# Merge tags wol and wake-on-lan on SF

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

The tags [[wol]](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/wol) and [[wake-on-lan]](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/wake-on-lan) in Server Fault should be merged.  They are clearly referring to the same topic and wol is just a short form of wake-on-lan.

wake-on-lan has 15 questions whereas wol has 8, so clearly wake-on-lan is the preferred option.

Answer (score 3):

I merged the tags as requested.